# System.InvalidOperationException: Client results inside OnConnectedAsync Hub methods are not allowed

Tags: .net-7.0, asp.net-core-signalr

Using the new Client Results feature in SignalR .NET 7, I'm facing an error that **client results inside OnConnectedAsync Hub methods are not allowed.**

My use case is that I have multiple clients, I cache the connection ID for each client using the **OnConnectedAsync** method so that I can send a message to specific clients and wait their response.

Here's my hub class, Note that the exception is thrown when I invoke the client method:

```
return await Clients.Client(connectionMetadata.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync<bool>("CreateConnection", message, CancellationToken.None);
```

```
public class ConnectionCreationHub : Hub
{
    private readonly List<ConnectionMetadata> connectionIdsCache;
    private readonly ITokenValidator2 validator;

    public ConnectionCreationHub(
        ITokenValidator2 validator,
        List<ConnectionMetadata> connectionIdsCache)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
        this.connectionIdsCache = connectionIdsCache;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendCreateConnectionMessage(
        Guid userId,
        string message)
    {
        var connectionMetadata =
            connectionIdsCache
                .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.UserId.Equals(userId));

        if (connectionMetadata == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Client with userId {userId} not connected");
        }

        //The following line throws an error "System.InvalidOperationException: Client results inside OnConnectedAsync Hub methods are not allowed."
        return await Clients.Client(connectionMetadata.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync<bool>("CreateConnection", message, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //Validate authorization token, and cache connection ID.
        var tokenClaims = await this.AuthorizeOrThrow(validator);

        var userId = tokenClaims.UserId;

        connectionIdsCache.Add(new(userId, Context.ConnectionId));

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        //Clean cache on client disconnected
        var connectionMetadata =
            connectionIdsCache
                .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);

        if (connectionMetadata != null)
        {
            connectionIdsCache.Remove(connectionMetadata);
        }

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

I expect that my client will receive the message, instead, I'm getting the error described above. Note that this happens only when using ***InvokeAsync***. ***SendAsync** is working as expected.

Here's the exception details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Client results inside OnConnectedAsync Hub methods are not allowed.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.HubCallerClients.NoInvokeSingleClientProxy.InvokeCoreAsync[T](String method, Object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.ClientProxyExtensions.InvokeAsync[T](ISingleClientProxy clientProxy, String method, Object arg1, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ConnectionCreationHub.<SendCreateConnectionMessage>d__3.MoveNext() in *\ConnectionCreationHub.cs:line 42
```

Answer (score 1):

In SignalR .NET 7, there is a restriction that does not allow awaiting client results within the OnConnectedAsync method's context, because the connection is not fully established until OnConnectedAsync completes.

**Known issue** : [Throw from OnConnected and OnDisconnected when using client results](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/42447)

[image]

*The optimized code is as follows, you can refer to it.*

```
public async Task<bool> SendCreateConnectionMessage(
    Guid userId,
    string message)
{
    var connectionMetadata =
        connectionIdsCache
            .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.UserId.Equals(userId));

    if (connectionMetadata == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Client with userId {userId} not connected");
    }

    //We need to ensure that this invocation is not in the lifecycle context.
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        result = await Clients.Client(connectionMetadata.ConnectionId)
            .InvokeAsync<bool>("CreateConnection", message, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception.
        throw new Exception($"Error while trying to invoke client method: {ex.Message}", ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```